# Rails: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Debug (postgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

It's giving me a hard time to debug this. It was working perfectly before I moved to PostgreSQL from SQLite3. What's strange to me is that there's another controller that has almost the same code as this, and that page works fine. Could anyone help me?

**Error:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Good_posts#index

Showing c:/ruby/mangfeel/app/views/good_posts/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "desc"
LINE 1: ...  "good_posts".* FROM "good_posts"  ORDER BY like desc LIMIT...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "good_posts".* FROM "good_posts"  ORDER BY like desc LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

**good_posts_controller** that's causing the problem:

```
def index
 @good_posts = GoodPost.paginate(:page => params[:page], order: 'like desc', per_page: 15)
 @good_client_ip = request.remote_ip.encode! 'utf-8'

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @good_posts }
 end
end
```

**post_controller**, which has similar code but works fine:

```
def index
 @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], order: 'created_at desc', per_page: 15)
 @client_ip = request.remote_ip.encode! 'utf-8'

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @posts }
 end
end
```

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: It seems that `ORDER BY` in Postgres is not accepting `ORDER BY LIKE field` notation.

Comment: Yes, I assumed a similar thing. But how would I fix it then?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `like` notation in this context. What will be the difference if you will just use `order: desc`?

Comment: Is `like` a column in your table? If yes you need to enclose it in double quotes as it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIKE is an operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) so you can't use it as a column name unless you double quote it:

```
@good_posts = GoodPost.paginate(... order: '"like" desc' ...)
```

Whenever ActiveRecord generates a column name in some SQL it will quote the column name for you; so `.where(:like => 11)` will be sent to the database as `where "like" = 11` and everyone is happy. When you write the column name in an SQL snippet (such as `.where('"like" = ?', 11)`) you'll have to double quote it to distinguish it from the pattern matching operator. You'll be happier if you rename the column to something (such as `likes` or `number_of_likes`) that doesn't conflict with a keyword